# Prove that there exist an $\varepsilon>0$ and $N$, such that for every $n\geq N$, $\mu(A_n\Delta A)\leq \varepsilon$

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, entropy, ergodic-theory

Lemma 4.7 in Ergodic Theory and Differentiable Dynamics by Racon, makes the statement,

> Let $A$ be in the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\lim_{n\to\infty}\bigvee_{i=0}^n\mathscr{A}_i$. Then for all $\varepsilon>0$, there exists an $N$, such that for all $n \geq N$, the union of atoms $A_n$ of $\mathscr{A_n}$, we have
> $$
>     \mu(A_n \Delta A) < \varepsilon
> $$

The proof there is very small, and it doesn't quite make sense to me, the proof given is

> The set of all such $A$ clearly contains $\bigcup_{i\geq 1}\mathscr{A}_i$. This is easily seen to form a $\sigma$-algebra.

This confuses me more than answering the question. How does it contain $\bigcup_{i\geq 1}\mathscr{A}_i$? and how does that form a $\sigma$-algebra? and above all of that, even if it does form a $\sigma$-algebra, how does that prove the statement?

I can't understand how to approach the proof by myself, and the proof here makes absolutely 0 sense to me for now. Can someone provide a proof for this lemma?

Comment: They are using the basic approximation theoerm of measure theory. For a proof see Halmos' book.

Comment: Thanks a lot 

Comment: So I think by basic approximation theorem you are referring to how measurable functions are approximated by simple functions? How is that related?

Comment: See Theorem D, p. 56 of the book.

Comment: in this theorem, wouldn't E_0 = E work all the time? why isn't there any other condition?